# Some attributes have no effect on TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, tttattributedlabel

Some attributes have no effect on `TTTAttributedLabel`, is this a known issue or limitation?

```
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: plainText, attributes: attributes)
attributedLabel.setText(attributedString)
```

the `attributes` var contains `NSExpansionAttributeName` amongst other attributes, but it has no effect. If I'm using a regular UILabel with the same attributes, no problem.

Comment: are you trying to add kerning to a label ?

Comment: @SeanLintern88 no I'm not, I know there's another attribute for kerning.